# ORACLE PL/SQL package taking hours to complete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle package which has input parameter as start date sysdate-365 and end date as sysdate+90. It finds each date from sysdate-365 to sysdate+90, which is 455 days, then it loops through for each date, get records from master table again loops through based on master table data, to get values from other table, do some logic and insert into working table. It is taking more than 10 hours to finish.

I thought of using dbms_scheduler to run package parallel, as it is not recommended by DBA. Can anyone suggest any other way to improve performance?

Code snippet:

```
loop for date range
select some_data from master_table where master_date = cursor.date;


loop for 
select other_data from other_table where other_date = cursor.date
start with some_data 
connect by other_parent = prior other_child;


select count(*) into v1cnt from third_table where third_date = cursor.date and third_data=other_data; 

if v1cnt  > 0 then
select third_data into variable1 from third_table where third_date = cursor.date and third_data=other_data; 
else
variable1 = null;
end if;

select count(*) into v2cnt from fourth_table where third_date = cursor.date and fourth_data=other_data;

if v2cnt  > 0 then
select fourth_data into variable2 from fourth_table where third_date = cursor.date and fourth_data=other_data; 
else
variable2 := null;
end if;


do some other logic.


insert into working_table (variable1,variable2 ,cursor.date, fields from other logics);

end loop;
end loop;
```

Comment: You should be able to rewrite most (if not all) of this logic in a single SQL statement - instead of doing loops within loops, try joining the queries into a single one. The count(*) queries can be done in sub-selects.

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on these tables? If these tables have a lot of records and the queries have to use a full table scan to find the records, they're going to be slow pretty much no matter what. Please edit your question and include the execution plan and the indexes defined on each table. Thanks.

Comment: Since the only answer is a bit snarky, and since the question is closed, I am voting to delete this question.

Answer (score 8):

This is a style of database programming known as Row By Agonizing Row (RBAR).  You see, SQL is a *set-based* language, designed to manipulate oodles of rows in a single operation.  By breaking down your logic into a series of operations, each working on a single row at a time, you have introduced a tremendous amount of overhead.

Now, running this program in parallel might reduce the overall elapsed time, but it would make the total resource usage even worse: you'd still be chewing up the CPU on all that RBAR processing, plus you'd have the additional overhead of managing parallel query.  No wonder your DBA advised against it.  What a shame they didn't advise you on how to fix your code.

It's pretty hard for us to give you an actual solution because we don't know what logic hides behind "do some other logic.".  However, all the code you have posted is pure SQL.  So it should be possible to replace all the PL/SQL with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

The actual SELECT might be somewhat gnarly, perhaps requiring sub-queries or the WITH clause ([find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048)) but it will be set-based and will likely perform orders of magnitude faster than your current program.  If you don't know how to write a complex query like that you should tap your DBA for some expert advice.

Comment: *What a shame they didn't advise you on how to fix your code.* possibly due to the fact that they might need to fix "this" code themself :)